# Send ffmpeg input from python variable

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I need send continuouns date to ffmpeg from python, I have tried but really dont know the best solution to make this, i have tried:

```
import subprocess as sp
import time

command = ["/usr/bin/ffmpeg",
           '-f', 'hls',
           '-c', 'copy',
           '-hls_time', '10',
           '-hls_flags', 'delete_segments',
           '-i', '-', # The imput comes from a pipe
           'index.m3u8' ]

proc = sp.Popen(command, stdin=sp.PIPE)

proc.stdin.write(open("video.ts", 'r').read())

proc.stdin.close()
proc.wait()
```

I get the error:

```
ffmpeg version N-80901-gfebc862 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 15, in <module>
    proc.stdin.write(open("video.ts", 'r').read())
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: `open("video.ts", 'r').read()` changed file content. Try binary mode(`rb`), don't convert file content with default encoding, probably you will be lose all headers bytes.

Comment: I have tried with 'rb' and .mp4 file but same error

Comment: `proc.stdin.write` not file object, interpreter will be change everything. And another point why try pushing non buffer data. How to allocate right data with hash over hash, your all index will be lose.